# How to setup Sendgrid and Microsoft Exchange so automatic replies use the "Reply-To" header instead of the "Sender" header from the original email?

Tags: email, header, exchange-server, sendgrid, reply

Here is the isssue:

I manage various websites.

These websites use Sendgrid to route form submissions to various email addresses in a Microsoft Exchange Server.

Sendgrid itself only routes emails if the "Sender" is from a recognized/validated domain. Assuming my domain is "@mycompany.com", all form submissions from all sites are sent with the "Sender" header equal to "no-reply@mycompany.com".

To partially circumvent this issue, the actual email address of the person filling the form (for example, john@gmail.com) is sent in the "Reply-To" header.

At the other end, these emails (the ones generated from the form submissions), are received by different accounts in the Microsoft Exchange server (each form in each site is associated with a different email address in MS-Exchange).

In many cases, these Microsoft Exchange accounts have "automatic replies" put in place for all incoming mail, so people filling the form can, for example, receive a "thank you for contacting us" email.

As far as I can tell, email client software (MS Outlook included) only recognizes the "Sender" header information for purposes of "automatic reply" (the "Reply-To" header is considered a security risk as it is hidden from the user and can be misused by third parties).

As a consequence, all "automatic replies" are routed back to the generic "no-reply@mycompany.com" account instead of the people who actually filled the form and gave their email addresses (in the "Reply-To" field).

Question:

Do you know of any way to circumvent this issue and have the "automatic replies" set in a way that the actual people filling the forms get the reply?

I tried looking in Sendgrid for any settings that would allow those form submissions (and only the form submissions) be routed, even if the email address in "Sender" is not from a verified domain.

I also tried to see if the "automatic reply" could be customized so it looks at the "Reply-To" header and not at the "Sender" header.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange Server rules can act on reply-to field. I think that the issue preventing auto-reply from Exchange Server to personal email (@gmail.com etc) is organization-wide remote domain settings in Exchange Server. Can you pls check Exchange Management Shell cmdlet:
Get-RemoteDomain

You may check further entries as
Get-RemoteDomain -Identity Contoso | Format-List

The main fields to check are : AllowedOOfType AutoForwardEnabled, AutoReplyEnabled fields.

If there are no specific entries for personal email domain, then the settings in "*" domain is effective for remote domain settings and it should be checked.

If possible,setting the reply-to field as anotheraddress@company.com which has the same domain with sender@company.com to see if Exchange Server takes care of the reply-to field may be helpful.